# Checking checkboxes with Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

Using Capybara I cannot for the life of me select a checkbox on my form.

In my request spec I've tried:

```
check("First Name")
page.check("First Name")
page.check("pickem_option_ids_10")
find(:css, "#pickem_option_ids_11[value='11']").set(true)
find(:css, "#pickem_option_ids_11").set(true)
```

Snippet from my form:

```
<div class="control-group check_boxes optional">
   <label class="check_boxes optional control-label">Options:</label>
   <div class="controls">
    <label class="checkbox">
     <input class="check_boxes optional" id="pickem_option_ids_10" name="pickem[option_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="10" />First Name
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox">
     <input class="check_boxes optional" id="pickem_option_ids_11" name="pickem[option_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="11" />Middle Name
    </label>
   </div>
</div>
```

I got some of the find() ideas from [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8297624/how-to-check-a-checkbox-in-capybara).

I've had some success in other specs where I have a single checkbox with a label of Active and I just say `check("Active")`.

Comment: This solution worked with me 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8297624/how-to-check-a-checkbox-in-capybara

Comment: Or more precisely this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14813623/1612469

Answer (score 10):

Had the same problem today, I looked around and this seemed to work:

```
find(:xpath, "//input[@value='10']").set(true)
```

of course you can replace '10' with anything you want - just check your HTML and use your value.

Hope that helps.

Comment: A Handy hint is to use Chrome Web Inspector to find your element and right click and select "Copy XPath"

Answer (score 2):

Capybara can't find checkbox `"First Name"` because your html is wrong. Your html should look like

```
<label class="checkbox" for="pickem_option_ids_10">First Name</label>
 <input class="check_boxes optional" id="pickem_option_ids_10" name="pickem[option_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="10" />
```

In your view code

```
= label_tag "pickem_option_ids_10", "First Name"
= check_box_tag "pickem_option_ids_10", 10
```

Then `check("First Name")` should work.

Otherwise you can `find("#pickem_option_ids_10").check`

Comment: Good point. I'm using the association helper from simple_form, which is where that markup is coming from. Unfortunately I don't know how to achieve your suggestion with it. However now that you mention it, the generated markup is kind of strange.

Comment: Sorry, never used simple_form. Does `find("#pickem_option_ids_10").check` work?

Comment: Failure/Error: find("#pickem_option_ids_10").check
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find css "#pickem_option_ids_10"

Comment: Well, you got some other page probably. Can be Rails error page.

Comment: I put in a save_and_open_page and when it opens the checkboxes aren't even visible. That would certainly be an issue.

Comment: Alright my newbness caught up to me. My seed data was never loaded into the test environment, therefore Options didn't exist to create checkboxes from.