# Capybara "check()" not checking field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I have the following form element

```
<div class="control-group no-margin">
        <div class="controls">
                <label for="user_terms_and_conditions" class="checkbox">
                    <input id="user_terms_and_conditions" name="user[terms_and_conditions]" type="checkbox" > I accept the Open Vault <a href="/blog/terms-and-conditions">Terms &amp; Conditions</a>
            </label>
            </div>
        </div>
```

but my capybara test is not properly checking the checkbox with the following

```
check 'user_terms_and_conditions' unless terms_and_conditions.nil?
```

or

```
find('#user_terms_and_conditions').set(true) unless terms_and_conditions.nil?
```

What am I doing wrong?  There is a validation in the model to make sure its true and it keeps returning the error that this must be checked.  When i do this with my eyeballs in the browser it works fine.

Comment: P.S. i've already tried http://stackoverflow.com/a/8297992/818007 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11549345/checking-checkboxes-with-capybara

Comment: Are you sure that `terms_and_conditions.nil?` is `false`? The capybara portion of your code works fine for me.

Comment: Yeah i have tried excluding that entirely so that is check its regardless since its required

Answer (score 0):

Turns out switching from selenium to webkit for the default_driver was all it needed to work.  For some reason selenium didn't like checking checkboxes in my environment.  I suppose I should have just used webkit from the start.