# How to test incrementing numerical id in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I have a checkbox form partial to select all, some or one class:

```
<p>
  <%= check_box_tag(:all) %>
  <%= label_tag(:all, "All subjects") %>
</p>
<p>
  <% @subjects.each do |subject| %>
    <%= check_box_tag(subject.id) %>  
  <%= label_tag(subject.id, subject.name) %>
  <br />
  <% end %>
</p>
```

Which generates the following HTML:

```
<p>
  <input id="all" name="all" type="checkbox" value="1" />
  <label for="all">All subjects</label>
</p>
<p>
      <input id="1" name="1" type="checkbox" value="1" />  
    <label for="1">English</label>
    <br />
      <input id="2" name="2" type="checkbox" value="1" />  
    <label for="2">Basket_Weaving</label>
    <br />
      <input id="3" name="3" type="checkbox" value="1" />  
    <label for="3">Math</label>
    <br />
</p>
```

I want to test that each subject is being displayed in the view using rspec -

```
it "should have a box for each subject" do
  @eval_selektor
  @student_group.subjects.each do |subject|
    response.should ??????
  end
end
```

I've tried `response.should have_selector('id' content: subject.id) but that throws`undefined method `include?' for 1:Fixnum` (besides not really making much sense), i've also tried xpath/css as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8297624/how-to-check-a-checkbox-in-capybara).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you try:

```
find("input[id='#{subject.id}']")
```

Comment: that gives me `NoMethodError: undefined method `find' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1:0x0000010471f098>`

Comment: where does your spec live?

Comment: spec/controllers/evaluations_controller_spec - i should note that perhaps I'm not using 'find' correctly.  I've looked at some other examples on SO but none seem to really match what I'm doing

Comment: find is supposed to be used in request/features specs only

Comment: ah, okay that makes sense then :p  what should i use in a controller spec?

Comment: You should not be doing such tests in controllers specs ;) They should go in features specs.