# Test with capybara and simple form won't check the checkbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, simple-form

I'm having quite a bit of trouble checking a terms of service box from simple_form in my capybara/rspec test.
Here is my validation:

```
validates :terms_of_service, acceptance: true, allow_nil: false
```

If I remove allow_nil: false then the specs all pass even if the box isn't checked. If I leave it, the validation causes the specs to fail.

Here is the code creating the form/checkbox:

```
  = f.label :terms_of_service, "I agree to the #{link_to 'Terms of Service', terms_of_service_path, :target => "_blank"}".html_safe
  = f.check_box :terms_of_service
```

The resulting html:

```
<label for="candidate_terms_of_service">I agree to the <a href="/terms_of_service" target="_blank">Terms of Service</a></label>
<input name="candidate[terms_of_service]" type="hidden" value="0">
<input id="candidate_terms_of_service" name="candidate[terms_of_service]" type="checkbox" value="1">
```

My attempts in my test which I've tried individually:

```
  page.find_by_id("candidate_terms_of_service").check
  find(:xpath, "//*[@id='candidate_terms_of_service']").set(true)
  find(:css, "#candidate_terms_of_service").set(true)
  check 'candidate[terms_of_service]'
  check 'I agree to the Terms of Service'
  find('#candidate_terms_of_service').check
```

And resulting failure:

```
  Failure/Error: let(:candidate) { create(:candidate) }
 ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
   Validation failed: Terms of service must be accepted
```

How do I check this box?

Comment: Have you tried click instead of check?

Comment: I did.  No luck.  I wound up just changing the terms of service language to be considered accepted by clicking sign up just to avoid all the hassle.

Comment: That's kinda funny. :)

Comment: Facepalmed when I realized I could just do it another way.

Answer (score 1):

This particular simple_form field gave me a lot of grief, and while I found several different ways mentioned to query and set it, none of them worked (some mentioned [in this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8297624/how-to-check-a-checkbox-in-capybara), others from [Capybara issues](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aclosed%20checkbox%20label)).

I found the following to actually work with a simple_form boolean with RSpec:

```
find(:xpath, "//label[@for='candidate_terms_of_service']").click
```

For the sake of completeness considering the different webdrivers and total solutions given, here are the other solutions found but resulted in **invalid selector errors**. The input selector would actually error about the inability to check simple_form's default hidden input; this error makes sense, the label is the visible and top-most element.

```
find('#active_form_terms_of_service').set(true)

# or select by label

find('label[for=active_form[terms_of_service]').click

# and select by label and value if multiple boxes 
# with the same ID (not sure why this would happen)

find("label[value='1']").click

# or select the input with xpath

find(:xpath, "//input[value='1']").set(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
find('#candidate_terms_of_service').check
```

Comment: No luck.  I added to the running list.  For what it's worth I tried removing allow_nil: false which not surprisingly let specs pass without me checking the box.