# Proper way to uncheck a checkbox in Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, checkbox, capybara, simple-form

What is the proper way to uncheck a checkbox in Capybara integration tests? I have a list of checkboxes that I need to uncheck. I have selected them all using `all`:

```
checkboxes = all("input[type='checkbox']")
```

In order uncheck each one I use `each`. According to the information I have found on the StackOverflow there should be three ways to uncheck a checkbox:

```
uncheck(field)
field.click
field.set(false)
```

In order to test whether these different methods I created the following tests (each of these was in a separate scenario on the same page):

Using `uncheck` it succeeded:

```
checkboxes = all("input[type='checkbox']")
checkboxes.each { |field| expect(field.checked?).to eq("checked") }
checkboxes.each { |field| uncheck(field[:id]) }
checkboxes.each { |field| expect(field.checked?).to eq(nil) }
puts page.body
save_and_open_page
```

Using `click` it failed, so I assume this is an improper way of unchecking the field:

```
checkboxes = all("input[type='checkbox']")
checkboxes.each { |field| expect(field.checked?).to eq("checked") }
checkboxes.each { |field| field.click }
checkboxes.each { |field| expect(field.checked?).to eq(nil) }
puts page.body
save_and_open_page
```

Using `set(false)` it succeeded:

```
checkboxes = all("input[type='checkbox']")
checkboxes.each { |field| expect(field.checked?).to eq("checked") }
checkboxes.each { |field| field.set(false) }
checkboxes.each { |field| expect(field.checked?).to eq(nil) }
puts page.body
save_and_open_page
```

I figured I would just use `uncheck`, but then I noticed something strange: the page.body still showed the checkbox as checked, even though I had asserted in the test that `checked?` was nil. `save_and_open_page` showed the same thing. It appeared as if the checkboxes had not changed since the page was loaded.

**Questions:**

- Why aren't `uncheck` and `set(false)` altering the form HTML? In
  order form my test to pass some element associated with `field` had
  to be unchecked. Is there some disconnect between `page.body` and
  what `uncheck` deals with?
- What is the canonical way of unchecking a checkbox? Since `uncheck` is part of the API and is easy to use it seems to be the proper function to call for this sort of thing, but the fact that it's not changing `page.body` concerns me.

**Related questions:**

- [How to check a checkbox in capybara?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8297624/how-to-check-a-checkbox-in-capybara)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Capybara implements `#uncheck` as `find(...).set(false)` so calling `set(false)` on an existing element or `uncheck` with a locator string are doing the same thing to the element, and will leave a box unchecked if it was already unchecked.  If you are using a JS capable driver (not the default rack-test driver) calling `#click` on a checkbox will toggle the state (unless some JS is capturing/blocking the clicks), so if you want the box unchecked you want to be using `uncheck` or `set(false)`

As for why it doesn't update the html, you are experiencing the difference between html attributes and properties.  Calling `uncheck` on the box changes the 'checked' property of the element, but that won't change the attribute (attribute remains at initial state, property is current state).  That is expected and correct, the property is what gets submitted with your form.

Note: the fact that #checked? is returning "checked" rather than `true` for the rack_test driver is a bug, and will be fixed in the next Capybara release.  You should be using something like `expect(field).to be_checked` rather than eq('checked') to not have issues in the future

Note: save_and_open_page - saves the html (attribute) and then loads it - it does not save the properties of elements, so it very well may show checkboxes in a state that they aren't actually in during the test

Comment: I was thinking `save_and_open_page` was like some sort of DOM snapshot. Since it's just the HTML of the original page the current behavior of my feature specs make sense. Thanks!