# Posting and validating a PHP array using jQuery/AJAX

Tags: php, jquery

I have a form that I am trying to post to php using jQuery ajax, and it needs to be validated first.

The field looks like this:

```
<select name="inquirymodule[]" id="inquirymodule[]">
<option value="" selected>Select an Inquiry Module</option>
<option value="1">Module 1</option>
</select>
```

Additional selectors can be added with jQuery to allow as many selections to be made as needed, and all values posted in the inquirymodule variable.

I have read elsewhere that I think I can post this variable using the value

```
jQuery('#inquirymodule').serialize()
```

But I have validation running on the select, to make sure something is selected before it is submitted.  Prior to making this an array variable, this worked:

```
jQuery('#inquirymodule').bind('change', function (event) {
    wizard.validate(true);
});
```

However I know that adding '`[]`' to the variable name will break the javascript here.

Any advice?

Comment: There is no point of using `[]` in your element id.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1239127/1095101

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the selector :

```
       $("select[name='inquirymodule[]']")
```

To bind the change event to all inquirymodule elements :

```
     $("select[name='inquirymodule[]']").on('change',function() 
        {
           //code here

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the `[]` from `id`, then try the validation.

Comment: How do I then handle the data form submission?  I need a varied number of items in an array submitted in the form, and the way I know how to do that in php is with a [ ] variable.  To be specific, the user needs to submit an unknown number of inquirymodule selections.

Comment: You can use the name with the [] for getting the values in array in php. But the id should be unique in the html file