# How to select all elements whose ID starts and ends with specific strings?

Tags: css, css-selectors

In CSS, how can I select all `<tr>` elements where their `id` begins with `section_` and ends with `_dummy`?

E.g. I'd like to select and apply styles to the following `<tr>`’s:

```
<tr id="section_5_1_dummy">
    <td>...</td>
</tr>

<tr id="section_5_2_dummy">
    <td>...</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: To create selector when ID contains brackets `[]` => you have to double escape them with ``\`` => `[id$=\\[something\\]` (matches e.g. `<div id="cool[something]" />`) Thanks goes to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1239127/1835470 (one escape is for string escape of ``\`` which then escapes the `[` and `]`). And [here is how I've added ``\`` to this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275886/backslash-inside-backquotes-in-a-comment)

Answer (score 126, accepted):

The following CSS3 selector will do the job:

```
tr[id^="section_"][id$="_dummy"] {
    height: 200px;
}
```

The `^` denotes what the `id` should begin with.

The `$` denotes what the `id` should end with.

---

`id` itself can be replaced with another attribute, such as `href`, when applied to (for example) `<a>`:

```
a[href^="http://www.example.com/product_"][href$="/about"] {
    background-color: red;
}
```