# CSS wildcard - look for match in middle of class

Tags: css

I have the following classes:

```
event-grid-image-over-text-1-column-carousel__top-controls
event-grid-image-over-text-2-column-carousel__top-controls
event-grid-image-over-text-3-column-carousel__top-controls
```

Is there any way to use a CSS wildcard to target anything between:

```
event-grid-image-over-text-
```

and

```
__top-controls
```

I know this is not correct but an idea of what I am after if at all possible.

> div[class*="event-grid-image-over-text-*__top-controls"]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16009755/how-to-select-all-elements-whose-id-starts-and-ends-with-specific-strings/16009756?