# Cypress use regex to retrieve elements with matching text in id

Tags: angular, cypress

I have multiple div elements with the id `features-#####` and `features-#####`, where the # is a dynamic figure.

How would I get Cypress to find all elements with the matching part of the id `features-`, and then click on the first or second in a programmatic manner?

This is that I have done so far, but I can't figure out hwo to use regex to retrieve all the elements I did then process them programmatically.

```
  describe('builder features component', () => {
    it('should allow the user to select a features component', () => {
      cy.get(el).should('div.id', /^features-\w+/).first().click();
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Cypress suggests using `data-` attributes to select elements. If you add `data-cy="builder-feature"` to all your features, for example, you won't have to care about regular expressions which will just slow your tests down.

```
cy.get('[data-cy="builder-feature"]').first().click()
```

See [Best Practices](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices.html#Selecting-Elements).

Answer (score 13):

**Rich Churcher** is right, the approach he mentioned should be your first choice. But in the event that you don't have control over the app and you cannot add `data-cy` attributes, you may use css selector syntax to achieve this.

```
const featuresSelector = '[id^="features-"]';
```

This will select any element with an id that starts with... See a good explanation at [How to select all elements whose ID starts and ends with specific strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16009755/how-to-select-all-elements-whose-id-starts-and-ends-with-specific-strings)

And then you may use this selector like this:

```
cy.get(featuresSelector).first().click(); // click the 1st element in the collection
cy.get(featuresSelector).eq(1).click(); // click the second element (index starts at 0)
cy.get(featuresSelector).eq(-1).click(); // click the last element
cy.get(featuresSelector).each((element, index, collection) => {
    // or event loop through the entire collection
})
```

Comment: How do we call this  '[id^=] selector, with ^ $ , or where can i see more examples of this

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Answer (score 2):

Uses the contains() function. The function can receive regex as a parameter

```
cy.contains(/^features-\w+/).click();
```

Comment: I don't think `contains` checks element `id ` attributes?