# Could not access the element if id has these "{}"braces

Tags: jquery

I have few text boxes whose ids are `A_NAME{0}`, `A_NAME{1}`, `A_NAME{2}`. I am not able access these textboxes values.

I used below command to access them.

```
$('#A_NAME{0}').val();
```

Can someone please help.

Comment: Checkout this answer - from reading it looks like {} are not legal characters http://stackoverflow.com/a/79022/1370442

Comment: `A_NAME{0}` is an invalid DOM ID. http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html

Comment: Technically valid in HTML5, though.

Comment: this is also true for square brackets, btw: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239095/find-dom-element-by-id-when-id-contains-square-brackets

Answer (score 6):

You need to escape brackets for this:

```
$('#A_NAME\\{0\\}').val();
          ^^  ^^
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akp4s3cm/)

Comment: Related documentation: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ "*To use any of the meta-characters [...] as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \\.*"