# Jquery javascript dropdown in a loop and calculation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I got a a dropdown list populating from a php while loop. There will be more than one select dropdown boxes. When i select any dropdown from the loop, the subsequent textbox should change the value.

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title></title>
      <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js'></script>
      <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
         $(window).load(function(){
         $("#category").change(function () {
         var dept_number = $(this).val();
         var price = $(this).find(':selected').data('price');
         $('#dept-input').val(dept_number);
         $('#price-input').val(price);
         });
         });//]]> 


      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <select id="category[]">
         <option value="1" data-price="10">Item 1 second</option>
         <option value="2" data-price="20">Item 2 second</option>
         <option value="3" data-price="30">Item 3 second</option>
      </select>
      <br><br>
      <label>Dept. num:</label>
      <input type="text" id="dept-input[]"></input>
      <br><br>
      <label>Price:</label>
      <input type="text" id="price-input[]"></input>
   </body>
</html>
```

This script is working with out the loop. How will i change it to work with the loop.. Thank you in advance

```js
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js'></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
$(window).load(function(){
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select").on('change',function () {
        var dept_number = $(this).val();
        var price = $(this).find(':selected').data('price');
        $(this).siblings('.deptip').val(dept_number);
        $(this).siblings('.priceip').val(price);
        $(this).siblings('.total1').val(price * $(this).siblings('.total').data('value'));
    });
});
});//]]> 

</script>
```

```html
<div class="base"> <!--Keep each group in base container-->
<table border="1"><tr>
    <td><select id="category0">
       <option value="1" data-price="10">Item 1 second</option>
       <option value="2" data-price="20">Item 2 second</option>
       <option value="3" data-price="30">Item 3 second</option>
    </select></td>
    <td><label>Dept. num:</label>
    <input type="text" class="deptip" id="dept-input"/><!--give them a class--></td>
    <td><label>Price:</label>
    <input type="text" class="priceip" id="price-input"/> <!--a class here too--></td>
    <td><label>Total:</label><input data-value="50" type="text" readonly class="total"/></td>
 <td><label>Total1:</label><input data-value="50" type="text" readonly class="total1"/></td>

</tr></table>
</div>

<div class="base"> <!--Keep each group in base container-->
<table border="1"><tr>
    <td><select id="category1">
       <option value="1" data-price="10">Item 1 second</option>
       <option value="2" data-price="20">Item 2 second</option>
       <option value="3" data-price="30">Item 3 second</option>
    </select></td>
    <td><label>Dept. num:</label>
    <input type="text" class="deptip" id="dept-input"/><!--give them a class--></td>
    <td><label>Price:</label>
    <input type="text" class="priceip" id="price-input"/> <!--a class here too--></td>
    <td><label>Total:</label><input data-value="50" type="text" readonly class="total"/></td>
 <td><label>Total1:</label><input data-value="50" type="text" readonly class="total1"/></td>

</tr></table>
</div>

<div class="base"> <!--Keep each group in base container-->
<table border="1"><tr>
    <td><select id="category2">
       <option value="1" data-price="10">Item 1 second</option>
       <option value="2" data-price="20">Item 2 second</option>
       <option value="3" data-price="30">Item 3 second</option>
    </select></td>
    <td><label>Dept. num:</label>
    <input type="text" class="deptip" id="dept-input"/><!--give them a class--></td>
    <td><label>Price:</label>
    <input type="text" class="priceip" id="price-input"/> <!--a class here too--></td>
    <td><label>Total:</label><input data-value="50" type="text" readonly class="total"/></td>
 <td><label>Total1:</label><input data-value="50" type="text" readonly class="total1"/></td>

</tr></table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/ssepbxfk/1/)**

> - **Categorize your multiple `selects` into some parent `div` container and assign class to `input` elements in each container**

**For ex:**

```
<div class="base"> <!--Keep each group in base container-->
    <select id="category">
       <option value="1" data-price="10">Item 1 second</option>
       <option value="2" data-price="20">Item 2 second</option>
       <option value="3" data-price="30">Item 3 second</option>
    </select>
    <label>Dept. num:</label>
    <input type="text" class="deptip" id="dept-input"/><!--give them a class-->
    <label>Price:</label>
    <input type="text" class="priceip" id="price-input"/> <!--a class here too-->
</div>

<div class="base">
    <select id="category1">
       <option value="1" data-price="10">Item 1 second</option>
       <option value="2" data-price="20">Item 2 second</option>
       <option value="3" data-price="30">Item 3 second</option>
    </select>
    <label>Dept. num:</label>
    <input type="text" class="deptip" id="dept-input"/><!--same goes here-->
    <label>Price:</label>
    <input type="text" class="priceip" id="price-input"/><!--and here too-->
</div>

<div class="base">
    <select id="category2">
       <option value="1" data-price="10">Item 1 second</option>
       <option value="2" data-price="20">Item 2 second</option>
       <option value="3" data-price="30">Item 3 second</option>
    </select>
    <label>Dept. num:</label>
    <input type="text" class="deptip" id="dept-input"/>
    <label>Price:</label>
    <input type="text" class="priceip" id="price-input"/>
</div>
```

> - **Write a common `jquery` `on change event` to `select` element.**

**For Ex:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){ //Write it in document.ready()
    $("select").on('change',function () {
        var dept_number = $(this).val();
        var price = $(this).find(':selected').data('price');
        $(this).siblings('.deptip').val(dept_number); //find its siblings with classname 
        $(this).siblings('.priceip').val(price);
    });
});
```

---

**Update**

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/ssepbxfk/2/)**

Hoping the `html` will be there for each group

```
<label>Total:</label><input data-value="50" type="text" readonly class="total"/><br/>
<!-- Added value fetched from php to data-value attribute of input-->
```

So your modified **JS** would be as below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select").on('change',function () {
        var dept_number = $(this).val();
        var price = $(this).find(':selected').data('price');
        $(this).siblings('.deptip').val(dept_number);
        $(this).siblings('.priceip').val(price);
        $(this).siblings('.total').val(price * $(this).siblings('.total').data('value'));//Add this line
    });
});
```

---

**UPDATE 2**

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/ssepbxfk/3/)**

For your current structure you could change your `script` as below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select").on('change',function () {
        var dept_number = $(this).val();
        var price = $(this).find(':selected').data('price');
        $(this).closest('table').find('.deptip').val(dept_number);
        $(this).closest('table').find('.priceip').val(price);
        $(this).closest('table').find('.total').val(price * $(this).closest('table').find('.total').data('value'));
    });
});
```

Basically here we are finding the `parent table` of the clicked `select` and then finding required elements within that `parent`

Comment: It is working fantastic. Thank you. I have one more doubt. I have a field called Total in all the loop with the select. Its a readonly field with a value. Now when i select from a dropdown, it should calculate price*total and show it another field. Its actually a continuation for me. Can u pls help me Guru with this also?

Comment: Or do i need to post as a separate question?

Comment: Total for each `select` group?

Comment: So `total` wil be `price*?`

Comment: Yes. Exactly. i have a field called total and total1 in each row.

Yes, if i select 'Item 1 second' it should take calculate value of data-price*total and display the total value in total1 field.

Comment: So what will be the value of `total` at first!! your said `data-price*total`

Comment: My php script will be bringing the value of total from a query.

Comment: Am i confusing you? Iam really sorry for that. Do you want me to explain it oncemore?

Comment: No No.. I got it.. Updating answer!!

Comment: @SujithNair Updated answer!! check and let me know!!

Comment: Thanx a lot. This is what i was expecting. Thank you so much.

Comment: Anytime.. happy coding.. :)

Comment: A small issue. When i put the fields inside a table, its not working? is there anything i have to takecare of?

Comment: You might need to post the proper structure to understand it!! Just post html structure or edit the fiddle once it is rendered in browser!

Comment: i have added the html in the question itself. Kindly have a look. Thanx

Comment: Updated answer @SujithNair

Comment: Thank you Guruprasad. It is working fine now. :) Thank you once again.:)

Comment: is it possible that i can give some if condition in the script. For example : if dropdown selected value == 'Item 1 second' { different calculation} and  if dropdown selected value == 'Item 2 second' { different calculation} etc etc??

Comment: yes you can!! but this should not go extended like this!! I mean this question has taken different path now!! Well in `on change` you can write `var selected=$(this).find('option:selected').text()` and then check `if(selected=="Item 2 second")` then do a different calculation store in in a `var` and assign it to `textbox`

Comment: iam really sorry for this. If any more doubts, i will make a different question. Really appreciate the help. Thanx

Comment: Anytime.. hope it helped.. :)

Comment: Yes it helped me a lot. Thank you so much. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the only problem in your code is that the resulting HTML contains `[]` square brackets inside of the `id` attribute of some elements. Removing them should fix your problem: **[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/8dfcg74L/)**.

Otherwise, if you cannot modify HTML then, *escape* the characters when trying to access them in JavaScript: **[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/5tnz1ymt/1/)**.

And for multiple `select` elements, you can do **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/yok5y65p/1/)**.

***Snippet:***

```js
var categories = $('select[id^=category]');
var deptNumbers = $('input[id^=dept-input]');
var priceNumbers = $('input[id^=price-input]');
categories.each(function(index) {
    $(this).change(function() {
        var dept_number = $(this).val();
        var price = $(this).find(':selected').data('price');
        deptNumbers.eq(index).val(dept_number);
        priceNumbers.eq(index).val(price);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="category[0]">
    <option value="1" data-price="10">Item 1 second</option>
    <option value="2" data-price="20">Item 2 second</option>
    <option value="3" data-price="30">Item 3 second</option>
</select>
<select id="category[1]">
    <option value="1" data-price="10">Item 1 second</option>
    <option value="2" data-price="20">Item 2 second</option>
    <option value="3" data-price="30">Item 3 second</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<label>Dept. num:</label>
<input type="text" id="dept-input[0]"></input>
<br>
<br>
<label>Price:</label>
<input type="text" id="price-input[0]"></input>
<br>
<br>
<label>Dept. num:</label>
<input type="text" id="dept-input[1]"></input>
<br>
<br>
<label>Price:</label>
<input type="text" id="price-input[1]"></input>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The script is working actually. Iam trying to change the script to work in a loop. Because the select boxes are coming inside a loop. There will be more than one select box and subsequent textboxes.

Comment: @SujithNair: modified the same snippet just now. I initially thought you would have multiple `select` elements but the same `dept-input` and `price-input` fields, but now I have modified to cater multiple fields as well.

Comment: Though I recommend getting rid of the `[]` square brackets in IDs: **[Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239095/find-dom-element-by-id-when-id-contains-square-brackets)** and **[Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)**.

Comment: Its working Tahir. Thankx a lot. 
 
It is working fantastic. Thank you. I have one more doubt. I have a field called Total in all the loop with the select. Its a readonly field with a value. Now when i select from a dropdown, it should calculate price*total and show it another field. Its actually a continuation for me. Can u pls help me with this also?

Comment: Or do i need to post as a separate question?

Comment: the _Total_ field is just one for the entire form or does it also loop in each _category_?