# How to get nested table tr field(.find) and set value using input[name]

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

How to set the value to the nested table's field? My table show in below:

```
<table id="first">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" id="type[0]" name="type[0]"/></td>
        <td>
            <table>
            <tr class="list"><td><input type="text" id="type[0].a[0].label" name="type[0].a[0].label"/></td></tr>
            <tr class="list"><td><input type="text" id="type[0].a[1].label" name="type[0].a[1].label"/></td></tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
<table>
```

I am trying to use find and input[] to set the value, but its failed to do so.

```
$("#first").find("table").find("tr:last").find('input[name="type['+i+'].a['+j+'].label"]').val("ABC");
```

But able to set the **first table** by using *.find*.

```
$("#first > tbody > tr:last").find('input[name="type['+i+'].a['+j+']"]').val("123");
```

Unable to get by using jquery find by class:

```
tr.list
```

I tried this as well, prompt undefined

```
alert($("#first table:last > tr.list").attr("id"));
```

My questions are:

- How to find the nested table?
- How to set the value to nested table?
- How to set value to the nested table either single or in arraylist?

Comment: The reason is that you are using wrong selector. `('input[name="type['+i+'].label"]')` this should be like this `('input[name="type['+i+'].a['+i+'].label"]').` But then also `type[0].a[1].label` wont be taken

Comment: Sorry..typo . I will edit my post. Btw, what selector I should use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you need to escape the selector (take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18402484/123415)).

But why not just use the id?

```
$("#type\\[" + i + "\\]\\.a\\[" + j + "\\]\\.label")
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var i = 0, j = 1;
  $("#type\\[" + i + "\\]\\.a\\[" + j + "\\]\\.label").val("custom value");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="first">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" id="type[0]" name="type[0]"/></td>
        <td>
            <table>
            <tr class="list"><td><input type="text" id="type[0].a[0].label" name="type[0].a[0].label"/></td></tr>
            <tr class="list"><td><input type="text" id="type[0].a[1].label" name="type[0].a[1].label"/></td></tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
<table>
```

Comment: I have tried. I am using jquery 1.11.3.min.js Unable to get/set the value. FYI. I am using *append* the data : $('#first').append(data);

Comment: are you hoping to get it into the `td` cell after the input or into the input itself?

Comment: I just want to set the value to the field inside nested table which is > name="type[0].a[0].label"

Comment: Thanks! Its work now. I make a mistake whereby I set the j value to 1 but table only consist of 0. I will amend my code. BTW, why need append "\\"?

Comment: For the selector you need to escape special characters (see the link in the question). To get the backslashes into the selector though, you need to escape them inside the string. So a double backslash in quotation marks gives you a string with single backslashes which tells jquery to read the square brackets and periods as regular characters (not special characters).

Comment: Okay. Thanks alot!