# How to access hidden field value using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have an accordion table and i want to get the row id values using Jquery and checkboxes.To make things easier i am using a hidden value field.when i try to do that hidden input id  always set to the last row value instead giving me all the values.

My accordion table innerHTML is like this

```
<div id="acc22" class="accBox">
<p class="accordianHead">
<div class="accordianBody">
<form id="form_22" action="" method="post" encoding="">
<div style="display:none;">
<table id="item_tbl_22" class="accTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
<thead class="greyBg paddingHead">
<tbody>
<input id="cloth_id22" type="hidden" value="72" name="fabric_id">
<input id="cloth_colour_id22" type="hidden" value="824" name="data[Cloth][cloth_id]">
<tr id="S3639-1-1_824" style=" ">
<tr id="S3639-1-2_824" style=" ">
<tr id="S3639-1-3_824" style=" ">

<tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</form>
</div>
```

This is my hidden id

```
 <input type="hidden" id="form_te[<?php echo  $id;?>]" value="<?php echo  $tbl_content;?>" />
```

This is my Jquery method

```
 $("input[name='s_i_width[]']:checked").each(function(event) {

printArray.push($('#form_te'+ this.value).val());
  console.log($('#form_te'+ this.value).val());
```

How to archive this?

Comment: where is `input` with `name="s_i_width[]"` ??

Comment: this is my checkbox  <input id="form_22s_i_widthS3639-1-1" class="className" type="checkbox" value="19100" name="s_i_width[]">

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about that, i think the special character need to add extra code.
Try this.

```
$("#form_te\\["+<?php echo  $id;?>+"\\]").val()
```

And thanks for this guys.
[Find DOM element by ID when ID contains square brackets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239095/find-dom-element-by-id-when-id-contains-square-brackets)

Comment: But you must put this code in ur same php file. so that the jquery element will generate correctly.

Comment: This gives me the id value last row of the table, not the selected values, if i select 3 checkboxes and it prints last 3 row id  3 times

Answer (score -1):

Did you tried

```
$('#form_te['+<?php echo  $id;?>+']').val()
```

Comment: Please check below answer.