# Keypress not Working inside the loop

Tags: javascript

I made a textbox inside a table that has id's same with table row count.
and I want to make a function inside the textbox with event keypress enter and + the keypress enter work fine but I don't know why the + keypress didn't run

this is my code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var result = 0;
  var textboxes = $('input[id="input[]"]');

  $(document).keypress(function(e) {
    for (i = 0; i < textboxes; i++) {
      if (e.which == 43) {
        result = result + parseInt($('#input[i]').val());
        $('#date_awal').val("");
      }
      if (e.which == 13) {
        result = result + parseInt($('#input[i]').val());
        $('#date_awal').val("");
        $('#date_awal').val(result);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

This is the html that i said it has same id's but the last part is increment

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var result = 0;
      var textboxes = $('input[id="input[]"]');

      $(document).keypress(function(e) {
        for (i = 0; i < textboxes; i++) {
          if (e.which == 43) {
            result = result + parseInt($('#input[i]').val());
            $('#date_awal').val("");
          }
          if (e.which == 13) {
            result = result + parseInt($('#input[i]').val());
            $('#date_awal').val("");
            $('#date_awal').val(result);
          }
        }
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table_data" class="table table-bordered" width="90%"><tbody><tr><td>643301</td><td></td><td></td><td>Hostazyme X15000 EPU</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>2.000,00</td><td>120</td><td>0</td><td>40</td><td>80</td><td><input type="text" name="input9" id="input9" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input9" id="input9" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input9" id="input9" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>613100</td><td></td><td></td><td>Santoquin / Ethoxiquin Liquid (I)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>1.385,51</td><td>7</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>7</td><td><input type="text" name="input10" id="input10" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input10" id="input10" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input10" id="input10" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>612300</td><td></td><td></td><td>Mold Inhibitor Punch (L/I)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>13.000,00</td><td>13</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>13</td><td><input type="text" name="input11" id="input11" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input11" id="input11" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input11" id="input11" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>609300</td><td></td><td></td><td>MOLD INHIBITOR POWDER (L/I)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>21.000,00</td><td>1.480</td><td>120</td><td>760</td><td>840</td><td><input type="text" name="input12" id="input12" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input12" id="input12" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input12" id="input12" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>608100</td><td></td><td></td><td>Choline Chloride Liquid (I)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>16.930,00</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td><input type="text" name="input13" id="input13" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input13" id="input13" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input13" id="input13" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>607100</td><td></td><td></td><td>Choline Chloride Powder (I)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>103.500,00</td><td>3.100</td><td>1.360</td><td>320</td><td>4.140</td><td><input type="text" name="input14" id="input14" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input14" id="input14" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input14" id="input14" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>634300</td><td></td><td></td><td>Canthaxathin</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>600</td><td>130</td><td>10</td><td>20</td><td>120</td><td><input type="text" name="input15" id="input15" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input15" id="input15" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input15" id="input15" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>630300</td><td></td><td></td><td>Fungex-MaxiMils(L/I)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>27.000,00</td><td>7</td><td>22</td><td>2</td><td>27</td><td><input type="text" name="input16" id="input16" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input16" id="input16" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input16" id="input16" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>628100</td><td></td><td></td><td>L-Threonine (I)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>37.000,00</td><td>240</td><td>1.600</td><td>360</td><td>1.480</td><td><input type="text" name="input17" id="input17" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input17" id="input17" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input17" id="input17" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>626300</td><td></td><td></td><td>Nopcozyme (L/I)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>5.400,00</td><td>216</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>216</td><td><input type="text" name="input18" id="input18" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input18" id="input18" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input18" id="input18" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>621300</td><td></td><td></td><td>Larvadex / Larvacide 10% (L/I)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>1.040,00</td><td>105</td><td>50</td><td>51</td><td>104</td><td><input type="text" name="input19" id="input19" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input19" id="input19" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input19" id="input19" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>685300</td><td></td><td></td><td>HEMICELL-HT</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>1.975,00</td><td>41</td><td>40</td><td>2</td><td>79</td><td><input type="text" name="input20" id="input20" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input20" id="input20" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input20" id="input20" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>683301</td><td></td><td></td><td>Butipearl (Kemin) Ca Butyarate</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>675</td><td>29</td><td>0</td><td>2</td><td>27</td><td><input type="text" name="input21" id="input21" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input21" id="input21" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input21" id="input21" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>677300</td><td></td><td></td><td>SOLMAX L/I</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>1.640,00</td><td>53</td><td>50</td><td>21</td><td>82</td><td><input type="text" name="input22" id="input22" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input22" id="input22" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input22" id="input22" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>677201</td><td></td><td></td><td>Nuvem (R&amp;D)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>1.150,00</td><td>46</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>46</td><td><input type="text" name="input23" id="input23" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input23" id="input23" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input23" id="input23" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>676300</td><td></td><td></td><td>Quixalud</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>4.580,00</td><td>270</td><td>0</td><td>41</td><td>229</td><td><input type="text" name="input24" id="input24" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input24" id="input24" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input24" id="input24" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>999999</td><td></td><td></td><td>Bin Hasil Ayakan sweeping</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>277.516,00</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>475</td><td>-475</td><td><input type="text" name="input25" id="input25" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input25" id="input25" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input25" id="input25" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>933201</td><td></td><td></td><td>Sel-Plex Mix</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>2.289,40</td><td>108</td><td>0</td><td>11</td><td>97</td><td><input type="text" name="input26" id="input26" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input26" id="input26" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input26" id="input26" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>706100</td><td></td><td></td><td>Lecithin oil (I)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>8.200,00</td><td>104</td><td>0</td><td>63</td><td>41</td><td><input type="text" name="input27" id="input27" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input27" id="input27" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input27" id="input27" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>699200</td><td></td><td></td><td>Ginseng (L)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>160</td><td>8</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>8</td><td><input type="text" name="input28" id="input28" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input28" id="input28" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input28" id="input28" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>694200</td><td></td><td></td><td>Nano Ca Butyrate</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>60</td><td>3</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>3</td><td><input type="text" name="input29" id="input29" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input29" id="input29" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input29" id="input29" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>665301</td><td></td><td></td><td>Toxisorb Premium (L/I)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>22.750,00</td><td>1.200</td><td>0</td><td>290</td><td>910</td><td><input type="text" name="input30" id="input30" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input30" id="input30" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input30" id="input30" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>661300</td><td></td><td></td><td>BETAINE (L/I)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>700</td><td>28</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>28</td><td><input type="text" name="input31" id="input31" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input31" id="input31" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input31" id="input31" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>658300</td><td></td><td></td><td>TERMIN 8</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>22.000,00</td><td>20</td><td>5</td><td>3</td><td>22</td><td><input type="text" name="input32" id="input32" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input32" id="input32" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input32" id="input32" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>657301</td><td></td><td></td><td>Mycosorb</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>850</td><td>34</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>34</td><td><input type="text" name="input33" id="input33" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input33" id="input33" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input33" id="input33" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>654205</td><td></td><td></td><td>Herbs R &amp; D</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>900</td><td>45</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>45</td><td><input type="text" name="input34" id="input34" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input34" id="input34" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input34" id="input34" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>671300</td><td></td><td></td><td>Acidal NC</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>21.000,00</td><td>400</td><td>1.000</td><td>560</td><td>840</td><td><input type="text" name="input35" id="input35" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input35" id="input35" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input35" id="input35" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>669302</td><td></td><td></td><td>Activate DA</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>5.000,00</td><td>320</td><td>0</td><td>120</td><td>200</td><td><input type="text" name="input36" id="input36" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input36" id="input36" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input36" id="input36" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>669301</td><td></td><td></td><td>BIOTRONIC TOP3 ( L/I )</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>16.575,00</td><td>663</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>663</td><td><input type="text" name="input37" id="input37" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input37" id="input37" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input37" id="input37" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>669101</td><td></td><td></td><td>BioTronic Top3</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>33.000,00</td><td>1.400</td><td>0</td><td>80</td><td>1.320</td><td><input type="text" name="input38" id="input38" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input38" id="input38" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input38" id="input38" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>665303</td><td></td><td></td><td>MYCOFIX PLUS</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>8.775,00</td><td>397</td><td>0</td><td>46</td><td>351</td><td><input type="text" name="input39" id="input39" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input39" id="input39" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input39" id="input39" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>304201</td><td></td><td></td><td>Chicken Feather Extrude (L)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>2.274,10</td><td>56</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>56</td><td><input type="text" name="input40" id="input40" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input40" id="input40" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input40" id="input40" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>304200</td><td></td><td></td><td>Chicken Feather Meal (L)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>207.086,85</td><td>3.046</td><td>2.930</td><td>1.800</td><td>4.176</td><td><input type="text" name="input41" id="input41" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input41" id="input41" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input41" id="input41" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>304100</td><td></td><td></td><td>Chicken Feather Meal (I)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>27.164,00</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td><input type="text" name="input42" id="input42" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input42" id="input42" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input42" id="input42" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>301300</td><td></td><td></td><td>Meat Bone Meal (L/I)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>423.537,20</td><td>2.427</td><td>10.701</td><td>1</td><td>13.127</td><td><input type="text" name="input43" id="input43" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input43" id="input43" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input43" id="input43" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>301100</td><td></td><td></td><td>Meat Bone Meal (I)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>22.147,00</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td><input type="text" name="input44" id="input44" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input44" id="input44" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input44" id="input44" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>401200</td><td></td><td></td><td>Rice Bran (L)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>497.926,55</td><td>8.846</td><td>9.072</td><td>8.775</td><td>9.143</td><td><input type="text" name="input45" id="input45" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input45" id="input45" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input45" id="input45" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>344300</td><td></td><td></td><td>LACTOSE (L/I)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>75</td><td>3</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>3</td><td><input type="text" name="input46" id="input46" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input46" id="input46" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input46" id="input46" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>331300</td><td></td><td></td><td>Milk Replacer (L/I)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>62.000,00</td><td>3.260</td><td>580</td><td>1.360</td><td>2.480</td><td><input type="text" name="input47" id="input47" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input47" id="input47" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input47" id="input47" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>306200</td><td></td><td></td><td>Fish Meal - Local (L)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>42.172,75</td><td>558</td><td>690</td><td>600</td><td>648</td><td><input type="text" name="input48" id="input48" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input48" id="input48" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input48" id="input48" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>304400</td><td></td><td></td><td>Chicken Feather Meal NS</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>1.410,00</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td><input type="text" name="input49" id="input49" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input49" id="input49" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input49" id="input49" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>210100</td><td></td><td></td><td>Corn Gluten Meal USA (I)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>367.442,00</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td><input type="text" name="input50" id="input50" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input50" id="input50" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input50" id="input50" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>209102</td><td></td><td></td><td>SUN FLOWER MEAL</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>7.781,30</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td><input type="text" name="input51" id="input51" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input51" id="input51" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input51" id="input51" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>205400</td><td></td><td></td><td>Rape Seed Meal NS</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>200</td><td>2</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>2</td><td><input type="text" name="input52" id="input52" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input52" id="input52" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input52" id="input52" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>201400</td><td></td><td></td><td>SBM (BK Kedelai) NS</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>280</td><td>165</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>165</td><td><input type="text" name="input53" id="input53" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input53" id="input53" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input53" id="input53" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>109201</td><td></td><td></td><td>PADI MERAH BASAH ( L )</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>8.561,30</td><td>173</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>173</td><td><input type="text" name="input54" id="input54" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input54" id="input54" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input54" id="input54" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>249200</td><td></td><td></td><td>Fermented Soyabean Meal ( L )</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>58.289,95</td><td>489</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>489</td><td><input type="text" name="input55" id="input55" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input55" id="input55" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input55" id="input55" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>241300</td><td></td><td></td><td>FullFat Soya Bean Meals US (L/I)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>63,35</td><td>965</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>965</td><td><input type="text" name="input56" id="input56" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input56" id="input56" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input56" id="input56" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>228300</td><td></td><td></td><td>DISTILLERS DRIED GRAINS W SOLUBLES (L/I)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>133.068,00</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td><input type="text" name="input57" id="input57" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input57" id="input57" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input57" id="input57" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>228100</td><td></td><td></td><td>DISTILLERS DRIED GRAINS WITH SOLUBLES</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>859</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td><input type="text" name="input58" id="input58" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input58" id="input58" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input58" id="input58" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>210300</td><td></td><td></td><td>Corn Gluten Meal USA (L/I)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>388.755,00</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td><input type="text" name="input59" id="input59" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input59" id="input59" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input59" id="input59" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>515200</td><td></td><td></td><td>Lime Stone Fine 2 (L)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>640.824,40</td><td>17.017</td><td>12.380</td><td>17.610</td><td>11.787</td><td><input type="text" name="input60" id="input60" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input60" id="input60" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input60" id="input60" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>514200</td><td></td><td></td><td>Lime Stone Chip 2 (L)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>1.016.272,60</td><td>18.447</td><td>9.190</td><td>11.132</td><td>16.505</td><td><input type="text" name="input61" id="input61" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input61" id="input61" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input61" id="input61" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>512200</td><td></td><td></td><td>BINDER 2 / BENTONIT</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>164.267,50</td><td>3.511</td><td>4.850</td><td>5.455</td><td>2.906</td><td><input type="text" name="input62" id="input62" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input62" id="input62" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input62" id="input62" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>506100</td><td></td><td></td><td>MDCP/MCP 21 % (I)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>106.150,00</td><td>1.800</td><td>2.000</td><td>1.677</td><td>2.123</td><td><input type="text" name="input63" id="input63" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input63" id="input63" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input63" id="input63" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>505100</td><td></td><td></td><td>Sodium Bicarbonate (I)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>18.503,25</td><td>936</td><td>0</td><td>196</td><td>740</td><td><input type="text" name="input64" id="input64" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input64" id="input64" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input64" id="input64" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>606200</td><td></td><td></td><td>Tryptophan 98%</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>2.180,00</td><td>40</td><td>200</td><td>22</td><td>218</td><td><input type="text" name="input65" id="input65" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input65" id="input65" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input65" id="input65" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>605101</td><td></td><td></td><td>L-LYSINE SULPHATE</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>45.750,00</td><td>1.810</td><td>2.860</td><td>2.840</td><td>1.830</td><td><input type="text" name="input66" id="input66" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input66" id="input66" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input66" id="input66" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>605100</td><td></td><td></td><td>L-Lysine (I)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>20.000,00</td><td>800</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>800</td><td><input type="text" name="input67" id="input67" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input67" id="input67" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input67" id="input67" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>603100</td><td></td><td></td><td>Alimet / MHA / Rhodimet AT88 (I)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>12.000,00</td><td>144</td><td>0</td><td>96</td><td>48</td><td><input type="text" name="input68" id="input68" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input68" id="input68" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input68" id="input68" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>601100</td><td></td><td></td><td>DL-Meth./Rhodimet/Met Amino Powder (I)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>58.000,00</td><td>82</td><td>0</td><td>24</td><td>58</td><td><input type="text" name="input69" id="input69" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input69" id="input69" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input69" id="input69" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>412200</td><td></td><td></td><td>Palm Karnel Meal (L)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>227.964,15</td><td>7.505</td><td>3.660</td><td>6.550</td><td>4.615</td><td><input type="text" name="input70" id="input70" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input70" id="input70" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input70" id="input70" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>406200</td><td></td><td></td><td>Wheat Flour (L)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>37.930,00</td><td>1.520</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>1.520</td><td><input type="text" name="input71" id="input71" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input71" id="input71" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input71" id="input71" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>405200</td><td></td><td></td><td>Wheat Bran (L)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>175.057,75</td><td>3.597</td><td>6.110</td><td>6.074</td><td>3.633</td><td><input type="text" name="input72" id="input72" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input72" id="input72" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input72" id="input72" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>404200</td><td></td><td></td><td>Pollard (L)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>72.255,35</td><td>1.505</td><td>100</td><td>150</td><td>1.455</td><td><input type="text" name="input73" id="input73" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input73" id="input73" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input73" id="input73" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>403200</td><td></td><td></td><td>Broken Rice (L)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>148.728,55</td><td>2.891</td><td>579</td><td>600</td><td>2.870</td><td><input type="text" name="input74" id="input74" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input74" id="input74" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input74" id="input74" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>504200</td><td></td><td></td><td>Salt (L)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>116.092,40</td><td>5.139</td><td>2.720</td><td>2.360</td><td>5.499</td><td><input type="text" name="input75" id="input75" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input75" id="input75" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input75" id="input75" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>426200</td><td></td><td></td><td>Corn Meal (Temulawak)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>5.633,90</td><td>145</td><td>0</td><td>60</td><td>85</td><td><input type="text" name="input76" id="input76" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input76" id="input76" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input76" id="input76" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>425200</td><td></td><td></td><td>GREEN LEAF POWDER PM (L)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>34.951,05</td><td>800</td><td>380</td><td>455</td><td>725</td><td><input type="text" name="input77" id="input77" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input77" id="input77" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input77" id="input77" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>420100</td><td></td><td></td><td>Caromic / Carob Meal</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>7.000,00</td><td>600</td><td>0</td><td>320</td><td>280</td><td><input type="text" name="input78" id="input78" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input78" id="input78" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input78" id="input78" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>414200</td><td></td><td></td><td>Mollasses (L)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>6.081,00</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td><input type="text" name="input79" id="input79" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input79" id="input79" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input79" id="input79" size="7"></td></tr><tr></tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: The `keypress` event *is* firing - your handler *is* running. But your selector `'#input[i]'` is probably wrong, and with `var textboxes = $('input[id="input[]"]');` it sounds like you have more than one element with the same ID, which is invalid HTML...? Or are they indexed numerically? (use `^=` selector instead)

Comment: yeah.. that was some element with one id's but it has a different at the last word in there. i use increment for the id's from i to i++

Comment: i have try the other way to get the id's but i'm still cant get it

Comment: the id's like `input[0] to input[x]` as much as the table has row. because i put the textbox inside the table row

Comment: i try to chage the code and try use `.length' still not work

Comment: can you show an example of html with your inputs?

Comment: my html is dynamic table. 
how about i try to make an example only?

Comment: `parseInt($('#input[i]').val());` **=>**  `parseInt($('#input[' + i +']').val());`

Comment: For get part of your dynamic html, press F12 (dev mode, works on main browsers) when page is rendered. You can use Inspect tool to select a piece of your page and see html .

Comment: try to change your selector `var textboxes = $('input[id^="input"]');`

Comment: i have edited my question contain my html table

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var textboxes = $('input[id^="input"]');

    $(document).keypress(function(e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            var result = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < textboxes.length; i++) {
                var $input = $(textboxes[i]);
                if ($.isNumeric($input.val())) {
                    result = result + parseInt($input.val());
                }
            }
            $('#date_awal').val(result);
        } else if (e.which == 43) {
            $('#date_awal').val('');
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
        }    
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Date Awal = <input id="date_awal" name="#date_awal" type="text">

<table id="table_data" class="table table-bordered" width="90%"><tbody><tr><td>643301</td><td></td><td></td><td>Hostazyme X15000 EPU</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>2.000,00</td><td>120</td><td>0</td><td>40</td><td>80</td><td><input type="text" name="input9" id="input9" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input9" id="input9" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input9" id="input9" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>613100</td><td></td><td></td><td>Santoquin / Ethoxiquin Liquid (I)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>1.385,51</td><td>7</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>7</td><td><input type="text" name="input10" id="input10" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input10" id="input10" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input10" id="input10" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>612300</td><td></td><td></td><td>Mold Inhibitor Punch (L/I)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>13.000,00</td><td>13</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>13</td><td><input type="text" name="input11" id="input11" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input11" id="input11" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input11" id="input11" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>609300</td><td></td><td></td><td>MOLD INHIBITOR POWDER (L/I)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>21.000,00</td><td>1.480</td><td>120</td><td>760</td><td>840</td><td><input type="text" name="input12" id="input12" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input12" id="input12" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input12" id="input12" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>608100</td><td></td><td></td><td>Choline Chloride Liquid (I)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>16.930,00</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td><input type="text" name="input13" id="input13" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input13" id="input13" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input13" id="input13" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>607100</td><td></td><td></td><td>Choline Chloride Powder (I)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>103.500,00</td><td>3.100</td><td>1.360</td><td>320</td><td>4.140</td><td><input type="text" name="input14" id="input14" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input14" id="input14" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input14" id="input14" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>634300</td><td></td><td></td><td>Canthaxathin</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>600</td><td>130</td><td>10</td><td>20</td><td>120</td><td><input type="text" name="input15" id="input15" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input15" id="input15" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input15" id="input15" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>630300</td><td></td><td></td><td>Fungex-MaxiMils(L/I)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>27.000,00</td><td>7</td><td>22</td><td>2</td><td>27</td><td><input type="text" name="input16" id="input16" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input16" id="input16" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input16" id="input16" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>628100</td><td></td><td></td><td>L-Threonine (I)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>37.000,00</td><td>240</td><td>1.600</td><td>360</td><td>1.480</td><td><input type="text" name="input17" id="input17" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input17" id="input17" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input17" id="input17" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>626300</td><td></td><td></td><td>Nopcozyme (L/I)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>5.400,00</td><td>216</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>216</td><td><input type="text" name="input18" id="input18" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input18" id="input18" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input18" id="input18" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>621300</td><td></td><td></td><td>Larvadex / Larvacide 10% (L/I)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>1.040,00</td><td>105</td><td>50</td><td>51</td><td>104</td><td><input type="text" name="input19" id="input19" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input19" id="input19" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input19" id="input19" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>685300</td><td></td><td></td><td>HEMICELL-HT</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>1.975,00</td><td>41</td><td>40</td><td>2</td><td>79</td><td><input type="text" name="input20" id="input20" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input20" id="input20" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input20" id="input20" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>683301</td><td></td><td></td><td>Butipearl (Kemin) Ca Butyarate</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>675</td><td>29</td><td>0</td><td>2</td><td>27</td><td><input type="text" name="input21" id="input21" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input21" id="input21" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input21" id="input21" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>677300</td><td></td><td></td><td>SOLMAX L/I</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>1.640,00</td><td>53</td><td>50</td><td>21</td><td>82</td><td><input type="text" name="input22" id="input22" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input22" id="input22" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input22" id="input22" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>677201</td><td></td><td></td><td>Nuvem (R&amp;D)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>1.150,00</td><td>46</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>46</td><td><input type="text" name="input23" id="input23" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input23" id="input23" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input23" id="input23" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>676300</td><td></td><td></td><td>Quixalud</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>4.580,00</td><td>270</td><td>0</td><td>41</td><td>229</td><td><input type="text" name="input24" id="input24" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input24" id="input24" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input24" id="input24" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>999999</td><td></td><td></td><td>Bin Hasil Ayakan sweeping</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>277.516,00</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>475</td><td>-475</td><td><input type="text" name="input25" id="input25" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input25" id="input25" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input25" id="input25" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>933201</td><td></td><td></td><td>Sel-Plex Mix</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>2.289,40</td><td>108</td><td>0</td><td>11</td><td>97</td><td><input type="text" name="input26" id="input26" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input26" id="input26" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input26" id="input26" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>706100</td><td></td><td></td><td>Lecithin oil (I)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>8.200,00</td><td>104</td><td>0</td><td>63</td><td>41</td><td><input type="text" name="input27" id="input27" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input27" id="input27" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input27" id="input27" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>699200</td><td></td><td></td><td>Ginseng (L)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>160</td><td>8</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>8</td><td><input type="text" name="input28" id="input28" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input28" id="input28" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input28" id="input28" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>694200</td><td></td><td></td><td>Nano Ca Butyrate</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>60</td><td>3</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>3</td><td><input type="text" name="input29" id="input29" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input29" id="input29" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input29" id="input29" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>665301</td><td></td><td></td><td>Toxisorb Premium (L/I)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>22.750,00</td><td>1.200</td><td>0</td><td>290</td><td>910</td><td><input type="text" name="input30" id="input30" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input30" id="input30" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input30" id="input30" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>661300</td><td></td><td></td><td>BETAINE (L/I)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>700</td><td>28</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>28</td><td><input type="text" name="input31" id="input31" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input31" id="input31" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input31" id="input31" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>658300</td><td></td><td></td><td>TERMIN 8</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>22.000,00</td><td>20</td><td>5</td><td>3</td><td>22</td><td><input type="text" name="input32" id="input32" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input32" id="input32" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input32" id="input32" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>657301</td><td></td><td></td><td>Mycosorb</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>850</td><td>34</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>34</td><td><input type="text" name="input33" id="input33" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input33" id="input33" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input33" id="input33" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>654205</td><td></td><td></td><td>Herbs R &amp; D</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>900</td><td>45</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>45</td><td><input type="text" name="input34" id="input34" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input34" id="input34" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input34" id="input34" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>671300</td><td></td><td></td><td>Acidal NC</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>21.000,00</td><td>400</td><td>1.000</td><td>560</td><td>840</td><td><input type="text" name="input35" id="input35" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input35" id="input35" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input35" id="input35" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>669302</td><td></td><td></td><td>Activate DA</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>5.000,00</td><td>320</td><td>0</td><td>120</td><td>200</td><td><input type="text" name="input36" id="input36" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input36" id="input36" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input36" id="input36" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>669301</td><td></td><td></td><td>BIOTRONIC TOP3 ( L/I )</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>16.575,00</td><td>663</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>663</td><td><input type="text" name="input37" id="input37" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input37" id="input37" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input37" id="input37" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>669101</td><td></td><td></td><td>BioTronic Top3</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>33.000,00</td><td>1.400</td><td>0</td><td>80</td><td>1.320</td><td><input type="text" name="input38" id="input38" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input38" id="input38" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input38" id="input38" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>665303</td><td></td><td></td><td>MYCOFIX PLUS</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>8.775,00</td><td>397</td><td>0</td><td>46</td><td>351</td><td><input type="text" name="input39" id="input39" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input39" id="input39" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input39" id="input39" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>304201</td><td></td><td></td><td>Chicken Feather Extrude (L)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>2.274,10</td><td>56</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>56</td><td><input type="text" name="input40" id="input40" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input40" id="input40" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input40" id="input40" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>304200</td><td></td><td></td><td>Chicken Feather Meal (L)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>207.086,85</td><td>3.046</td><td>2.930</td><td>1.800</td><td>4.176</td><td><input type="text" name="input41" id="input41" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input41" id="input41" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input41" id="input41" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>304100</td><td></td><td></td><td>Chicken Feather Meal (I)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>27.164,00</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td><input type="text" name="input42" id="input42" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input42" id="input42" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input42" id="input42" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>301300</td><td></td><td></td><td>Meat Bone Meal (L/I)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>423.537,20</td><td>2.427</td><td>10.701</td><td>1</td><td>13.127</td><td><input type="text" name="input43" id="input43" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input43" id="input43" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input43" id="input43" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>301100</td><td></td><td></td><td>Meat Bone Meal (I)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>22.147,00</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td><input type="text" name="input44" id="input44" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input44" id="input44" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input44" id="input44" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>401200</td><td></td><td></td><td>Rice Bran (L)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>497.926,55</td><td>8.846</td><td>9.072</td><td>8.775</td><td>9.143</td><td><input type="text" name="input45" id="input45" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input45" id="input45" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input45" id="input45" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>344300</td><td></td><td></td><td>LACTOSE (L/I)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>75</td><td>3</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>3</td><td><input type="text" name="input46" id="input46" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input46" id="input46" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input46" id="input46" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>331300</td><td></td><td></td><td>Milk Replacer (L/I)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>62.000,00</td><td>3.260</td><td>580</td><td>1.360</td><td>2.480</td><td><input type="text" name="input47" id="input47" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input47" id="input47" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input47" id="input47" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>306200</td><td></td><td></td><td>Fish Meal - Local (L)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>42.172,75</td><td>558</td><td>690</td><td>600</td><td>648</td><td><input type="text" name="input48" id="input48" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input48" id="input48" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input48" id="input48" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>304400</td><td></td><td></td><td>Chicken Feather Meal NS</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>1.410,00</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td><input type="text" name="input49" id="input49" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input49" id="input49" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input49" id="input49" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>210100</td><td></td><td></td><td>Corn Gluten Meal USA (I)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>367.442,00</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td><input type="text" name="input50" id="input50" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input50" id="input50" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input50" id="input50" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>209102</td><td></td><td></td><td>SUN FLOWER MEAL</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>7.781,30</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td><input type="text" name="input51" id="input51" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input51" id="input51" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input51" id="input51" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>205400</td><td></td><td></td><td>Rape Seed Meal NS</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>200</td><td>2</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>2</td><td><input type="text" name="input52" id="input52" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input52" id="input52" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input52" id="input52" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>201400</td><td></td><td></td><td>SBM (BK Kedelai) NS</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>280</td><td>165</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>165</td><td><input type="text" name="input53" id="input53" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input53" id="input53" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input53" id="input53" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>109201</td><td></td><td></td><td>PADI MERAH BASAH ( L )</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>8.561,30</td><td>173</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>173</td><td><input type="text" name="input54" id="input54" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input54" id="input54" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input54" id="input54" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>249200</td><td></td><td></td><td>Fermented Soyabean Meal ( L )</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>58.289,95</td><td>489</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>489</td><td><input type="text" name="input55" id="input55" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input55" id="input55" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input55" id="input55" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>241300</td><td></td><td></td><td>FullFat Soya Bean Meals US (L/I)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>63,35</td><td>965</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>965</td><td><input type="text" name="input56" id="input56" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input56" id="input56" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input56" id="input56" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>228300</td><td></td><td></td><td>DISTILLERS DRIED GRAINS W SOLUBLES (L/I)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>133.068,00</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td><input type="text" name="input57" id="input57" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input57" id="input57" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input57" id="input57" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>228100</td><td></td><td></td><td>DISTILLERS DRIED GRAINS WITH SOLUBLES</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>859</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td><input type="text" name="input58" id="input58" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input58" id="input58" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input58" id="input58" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>210300</td><td></td><td></td><td>Corn Gluten Meal USA (L/I)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>388.755,00</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td><input type="text" name="input59" id="input59" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input59" id="input59" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input59" id="input59" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>515200</td><td></td><td></td><td>Lime Stone Fine 2 (L)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>640.824,40</td><td>17.017</td><td>12.380</td><td>17.610</td><td>11.787</td><td><input type="text" name="input60" id="input60" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input60" id="input60" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input60" id="input60" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>514200</td><td></td><td></td><td>Lime Stone Chip 2 (L)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>1.016.272,60</td><td>18.447</td><td>9.190</td><td>11.132</td><td>16.505</td><td><input type="text" name="input61" id="input61" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input61" id="input61" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input61" id="input61" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>512200</td><td></td><td></td><td>BINDER 2 / BENTONIT</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>164.267,50</td><td>3.511</td><td>4.850</td><td>5.455</td><td>2.906</td><td><input type="text" name="input62" id="input62" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input62" id="input62" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input62" id="input62" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>506100</td><td></td><td></td><td>MDCP/MCP 21 % (I)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>106.150,00</td><td>1.800</td><td>2.000</td><td>1.677</td><td>2.123</td><td><input type="text" name="input63" id="input63" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input63" id="input63" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input63" id="input63" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>505100</td><td></td><td></td><td>Sodium Bicarbonate (I)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>18.503,25</td><td>936</td><td>0</td><td>196</td><td>740</td><td><input type="text" name="input64" id="input64" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input64" id="input64" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input64" id="input64" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>606200</td><td></td><td></td><td>Tryptophan 98%</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>2.180,00</td><td>40</td><td>200</td><td>22</td><td>218</td><td><input type="text" name="input65" id="input65" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input65" id="input65" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input65" id="input65" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>605101</td><td></td><td></td><td>L-LYSINE SULPHATE</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>45.750,00</td><td>1.810</td><td>2.860</td><td>2.840</td><td>1.830</td><td><input type="text" name="input66" id="input66" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input66" id="input66" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input66" id="input66" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>605100</td><td></td><td></td><td>L-Lysine (I)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>20.000,00</td><td>800</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>800</td><td><input type="text" name="input67" id="input67" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input67" id="input67" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input67" id="input67" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>603100</td><td></td><td></td><td>Alimet / MHA / Rhodimet AT88 (I)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>12.000,00</td><td>144</td><td>0</td><td>96</td><td>48</td><td><input type="text" name="input68" id="input68" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input68" id="input68" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input68" id="input68" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>601100</td><td></td><td></td><td>DL-Meth./Rhodimet/Met Amino Powder (I)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>58.000,00</td><td>82</td><td>0</td><td>24</td><td>58</td><td><input type="text" name="input69" id="input69" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input69" id="input69" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input69" id="input69" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>412200</td><td></td><td></td><td>Palm Karnel Meal (L)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>227.964,15</td><td>7.505</td><td>3.660</td><td>6.550</td><td>4.615</td><td><input type="text" name="input70" id="input70" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input70" id="input70" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input70" id="input70" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>406200</td><td></td><td></td><td>Wheat Flour (L)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>37.930,00</td><td>1.520</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>1.520</td><td><input type="text" name="input71" id="input71" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input71" id="input71" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input71" id="input71" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>405200</td><td></td><td></td><td>Wheat Bran (L)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>175.057,75</td><td>3.597</td><td>6.110</td><td>6.074</td><td>3.633</td><td><input type="text" name="input72" id="input72" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input72" id="input72" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input72" id="input72" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>404200</td><td></td><td></td><td>Pollard (L)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>72.255,35</td><td>1.505</td><td>100</td><td>150</td><td>1.455</td><td><input type="text" name="input73" id="input73" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input73" id="input73" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input73" id="input73" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>403200</td><td></td><td></td><td>Broken Rice (L)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>148.728,55</td><td>2.891</td><td>579</td><td>600</td><td>2.870</td><td><input type="text" name="input74" id="input74" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input74" id="input74" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input74" id="input74" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>504200</td><td></td><td></td><td>Salt (L)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>116.092,40</td><td>5.139</td><td>2.720</td><td>2.360</td><td>5.499</td><td><input type="text" name="input75" id="input75" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input75" id="input75" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input75" id="input75" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>426200</td><td></td><td></td><td>Corn Meal (Temulawak)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>5.633,90</td><td>145</td><td>0</td><td>60</td><td>85</td><td><input type="text" name="input76" id="input76" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input76" id="input76" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input76" id="input76" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>425200</td><td></td><td></td><td>GREEN LEAF POWDER PM (L)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>34.951,05</td><td>800</td><td>380</td><td>455</td><td>725</td><td><input type="text" name="input77" id="input77" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input77" id="input77" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input77" id="input77" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>420100</td><td></td><td></td><td>Caromic / Carob Meal</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>7.000,00</td><td>600</td><td>0</td><td>320</td><td>280</td><td><input type="text" name="input78" id="input78" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input78" id="input78" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input78" id="input78" size="7"></td></tr><tr><td>414200</td><td></td><td></td><td>Mollasses (L)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>6.081,00</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td><input type="text" name="input79" id="input79" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input79" id="input79" size="2"></td><td><input type="text" name="input79" id="input79" size="7"></td></tr><tr></tr></tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 4 issues on your code :

1. `$('input[id="input[]"]');` this doesn't work. You need to use the same className.
2. `for (i = 0; i < textboxes; i++)` it's textboxes.length. *And you forget to declare `i`.*
3. `$('#input[i]')` jquery understand : Get input with id "Input" and attr "i". **EDIT :**
   You can read this : [`$("#something\\["+id+"\\]")`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1239127/2226755).
4. `var result = 0;` You will get an issue if you don't declare your variable on keypress function.

```js
function getResult(ev) {
  const $textboxes = $('#table_data > tbody > tr > td > input[id^="input"]');
  let result = 0;
  if (ev.which === 43)
    return $('#date_awal').val("");
  else if (ev.which !== 13)
    return;

  for (let i = 0, val; i < $textboxes.length; i++) {
    val = $textboxes.eq(i).val();
    if (isNaN(val))
      continue;
    result += +$textboxes.eq(i).val();
  }

  $('#date_awal').val(result);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).keypress(getResult);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table_data" class="table table-bordered" width="90%">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>405200</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Wheat Bran (L)</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>175.057,75</td>
      <td>3.597</td>
      <td>6.110</td>
      <td>6.074</td>
      <td>3.633</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="input72" id="input72" size="2"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="input72" id="input72" size="2"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="input72" id="input72" size="7"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>404200</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Pollard (L)</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>72.255,35</td>
      <td>1.505</td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td>150</td>
      <td>1.455</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="input73" id="input73" size="2"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="input73" id="input73" size="2"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="input73" id="input73" size="7"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>403200</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Broken Rice (L)</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>148.728,55</td>
      <td>2.891</td>
      <td>579</td>
      <td>600</td>
      <td>2.870</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="input74" id="input74" size="2"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="input74" id="input74" size="2"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="input74" id="input74" size="7"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>504200</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Salt (L)</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>116.092,40</td>
      <td>5.139</td>
      <td>2.720</td>
      <td>2.360</td>
      <td>5.499</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="input75" id="input75" size="2"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="input75" id="input75" size="2"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="input75" id="input75" size="7"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>426200</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Corn Meal (Temulawak)</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>5.633,90</td>
      <td>145</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>60</td>
      <td>85</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="input76" id="input76" size="2"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="input76" id="input76" size="2"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="input76" id="input76" size="7"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>425200</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>GREEN LEAF POWDER PM (L)</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>34.951,05</td>
      <td>800</td>
      <td>380</td>
      <td>455</td>
      <td>725</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="input77" id="input77" size="2"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="input77" id="input77" size="2"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="input77" id="input77" size="7"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>420100</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Caromic / Carob Meal</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>7.000,00</td>
      <td>600</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>320</td>
      <td>280</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="input78" id="input78" size="2"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="input78" id="input78" size="2"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="input78" id="input78" size="7" value="15"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>414200</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Mollasses (L)</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>6.081,00</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="input79" id="input79" size="2"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="input79" id="input79" size="2"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="input79" id="input79" size="7" value="12"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<input id="date_awal" />
```

> that still using the value from the textbox input. that i mean like my example from my fiddle. in my fiddle i use 1 textbox for calculate every number i put inside them. nah what i need is that function will work on every textbox input that i made. – Minervaz Mine

```
function getResult(ev) {
  const $textboxes = $('#table_data > tbody > tr > td > input[id^="input"]');
  let result = 0;

  for (let i = 0, val; i < $textboxes.length; i++) {
    val = $textboxes.eq(i).val();
    if (isNaN(val))
      continue;
    result += +$textboxes.eq(i).val();
  }

  $('#date_awal').val(result);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input").keypress(getResult);
});
```

Comment: im sorry.. i have wrong with my code.
the code of id's must be `input[0] to input[x]`

i have try to modified your code but still the key press 43 not work

Comment: in your answer i want to use the calculate method of id's `date_awal` inside all of id's `input`

Comment: yeah. that will clear the value of `date_awal` input data and it will save it as a log for a while. when the 13 pressed it will out the calculate data from the log right

Comment: wait'' i have wrong. from your code.
it calculate from the id's input

Comment: this is my original code 
that i try 1st into one textbox.

and i want to use into all of my textbox 
`$(document).ready(function() {
    var result = 0;
    $(document).keypress(function(e) {
        if (e.which == 43 ) {
            result = result + parseInt($('#input[i]').val());
            $('#date_awal').val("");
        }
        if (e.which == 13) {
            result = result + parseInt($('#input[i]').val());
   $('#date_awal').val("");
            $('#date_awal').val(result);
        }
 
    });
});`

Comment: like this fiddle my original code https://jsfiddle.net/minervaz/4zeq6ud3/1/

Comment: @MinervazMine I am writing new answer

Comment: that still using the value from the textbox input.
that i mean like my example from my fiddle. 
in my fiddle i use 1 textbox for calculate every number i put inside them.
nah what i need is that function will work on every textbox input that i made.

Comment: `$("input").keypress(getResult);` and `$("new_input").keypress(getResult);` you can remove `ev.which ===` condition.

Comment: hmm.. i think you didn't get what im thinking bro.
did you see my fiddle?
at my fiddle i made a code for calculate a number inside textbox `date_awal`.

nah.. my problem is make that function into every textbox `input`

Comment: hmm.. i think you didn't get what im thinking bro.
did you see my fiddle?
at my fiddle i made a code for calculate a number inside textbox `date_awal`.

nah.. my problem is make that function into every textbox `input`