# target multiple empty input fields with same id containing brackets

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a couple of input fields with the following ID:

```
<input type="text" name="numberC[]" id="numberC[]">
<input type="text" name="numberC[]" id="numberC[]">
<input type="text" name="numberC[]" id="numberC[]">
```

I fetch data in JSON format via my ajax call and `push()` certain values in my array.

How could I create a loop that will loop through the array and then inserts each value in one of the above input fields?

so let's say I have the following array:

```
var testArray = ['hi', 'bye', 'stackoverflow'];
```

and I have the following 3 input fields:

```
<input type="text" name="numberC[]" id="numberC[]">
<input type="text" name="numberC[]" id="numberC[]">
<input type="text" name="numberC[]" id="numberC[]">
```

Whenever I loop through it I unfortunately get the highest value in all of my input fields.

I try to loop through my array in JavaScript and insert each value in each input field. so `testArray[0]` should go in the first input field, `testArray[1]` in the second input field and `testArray[2]` in the third.

Sources I used: [Find DOM element by ID when ID contains square brackets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239095/find-dom-element-by-id-when-id-contains-square-brackets)

Comment: You should never have multiple elements with the same ID

Comment: `<input type="text" id="numberC\\[" + "\\]">` - that doesn’t even make sense, if that is supposed to be the final HTML code. The value of the id attribute would end at the second `"`, so the actual id here would be just `numberC\\[`

Comment: Check the source I included. I understand the misunderstanding from your side 04FS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `id` in  dom is always unique.Instead use `document.querySelectorAll` to get all the element with same name then loop through them and use the `index` to check if an element exist in the index of `testArray`. If so then set the value of the input

```js
var testArray = ['hi', 'bye', 'stackoverflow'];
document.querySelectorAll('[name="numberC[]"]').forEach(function(item, index) {
  if (testArray[index]) {
    item.value = testArray[index]
  }

})
```

```html
<input type="text" name="numberC[]" id="numberC[1]">
<input type="text" name="numberC[]" id="numberC[2]">
<input type="text" name="numberC[]" id="numberC[3]">
```

Comment: This is a genius solution. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you change your HTML to have different ids

```html
<input type="text" id="numberC[1]"/>
<input type="text" id="numberC[2]"/>
<input type="text" id="numberC[3]"/>
```

you can easily set the values like this:

```js
    var testArray = ['hi', 'bye', 'stackoverflow'];
    for(let i in testArray) {
        document.querySelector('#numberC\\[' + (+i+1) + '\\]').value = testArray[i];
    }
```